# What the standard used by a "hybrid PDF file"?

Tags: pdf, hybrid

I need to create [Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_formats) and easily-readable  "PDF with source-content" (also named *PDF Hybrid*) by [**software tool** like Prince or PDFreactor](https://print-css.rocks/)...  This [DocumentFoundation's FAQ explain what it is a *PDF Hybrid*](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Writer/PDF_Hybrid), but not say what standard is using:

- `PDF/A-3` of [ISO 19005-3](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000360.shtml)?
- Other (simplest?) ISO 19005 feature?
- Something of the [ISO 32000](https://talkingpdf.org/is-pdf-an-open-standard/)? (something as [embedded files](https://openpreservation.org/blogs/what-do-we-mean-embedded-files-pdf/)?)

---

Detecting the standard of a known hybrid PDF file would be a good alternative approach... But some people say that it is [impossible to detect  the standard](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/openoffice-and-libreoffice-how-to-manage-hybrid-pdfs) used in the *PDF Hybrid* file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this *Hybrid PDF* appears **not** to be specified in an independent standard, i.e. there is no corresponding ISO/ETSI/ANSI/... standard for it.

That being said, it apparently is in particular a prominent feature of LibreOffice PDF exports:

[image: LibreOffice PDF export options]

*(from the [LibreOffice Writer FAQ on hybrid PDFs](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Writer/PDF_Hybrid#To_create_a_hybrid_PDF))*

Inspecting such a file (e.g. [this one](http://webpages.csus.edu/zeigler/Computing/Hybrid-PDF.pdf)) one sees that there are additional entries in the PDF trailer:

```cos
...
trailer
<</Size 128/Root 126 0 R
/Info 127 0 R
/ID [ <518EBB4C2FE2F6B638478335A7ED9CA4>
<518EBB4C2FE2F6B638478335A7ED9CA4> ]
/DocChecksum /7B00A6EE0349EB2EA1DFB5ECC5899A7C
/AdditionalStreams [/application#2Fvnd#2Eoasis#2Eopendocument#2Etext 66 0 R
]
>>
startxref
291605
%%EOF
```

and that referenced *additional stream* in object 66 indeed contains the source OpenOffice document.

Apparently applications supporting these *hybrid PDF* files inspect the value of that **AdditionalStreams** trailer entry, and if they know to handle the given document type (`/application#2Fvnd#2Eoasis#2Eopendocument#2Etext` here corresponds to **application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text**), they provide a way to extract that embedded document and open it for editing.

---

**Beware:** Unless I overlooked some ISO norm, those extra entries strictly speaking are *forbidden* by the PDF specification ISO 32000: In the trailer there may only be entries with keys that are either defined for the trailer in ISO specifications or *any second-class names*. Neither **AdditionalStreams** nor **DocChecksum** are ISO specified or second class. Thus, strictly speaking those *hybrid PDFs* are invalid PDFs.